# Add individual state county borders to an ArcMap project?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, county, emergency-services

I am working on an emergency response mapping project for our Tribe and I want to develop emergency response maps for individual counties instead of the whole state. Our ArcMap has all the counties in one shapefile.

Is there a way to map individual counties so my maps don't look so cluttered and noisy with information?

I use ArcMap 10.1

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on what you are looking for?  This seems like something that a map book would be great for--but I'm unsure I understand what you mean by your maps being 'cluttered and noisy'--if you are zooming into an individual county, what issues are you having with the data?

Comment: There is a lot of information added to these "Emergency Response Maps" such as school locations, emergency response program locations and assets, population densities, main roads culturally sensitive areas, environmentally sensitive areas, ect. and if I include the entire area the tribe is located everything gets bunched up and it is hard to determine distances between a school and a hospital for example.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way were I can just map a single county outline and have the corresponding information for that county mapped instead of the whole state. I hope that's makes sense, I am fairly new at the GIS world and I am finding this site extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

On main menu bar, there is the option for "Selection", click on it and then there is an option for "Select by Attribute". This will open a new window, if you have more than one layer for your map, please select the layer that has the counties. This should populate the list of attributes for the counties--use the one that has the list of name. Select it and in the lower box it should add the "name" option in the select* from box , the "Get Unique values." Then select the county that you need. This should highlight the selected county. Right click on the counties layer, find selection and then select the option of "Create layer from selected features."  This will create a new layer that will only have the county that you want. Do this for all the counties you need to separate from the group of counties. Then you can click each layer on and off to show counties individually.

Comment: When I make it to the "Get unique Values" step and double click the desired county and click ok or apply and error window comes up saying exactly this

There was an error executing the query.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
An invalid SQL statement was used .

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I had to work around the error. I went to the attribute table and selected the desired county. After the county boarder was selected I created a layer from selected features. After that I had to right click on the created layer - "selection" - "make this the only selectable layer". This locked the layer to only the desired county. Now I can change the boarder thickness and color without it affecting the other counties.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:
Use a definition query in layer properties on the County layer. "COUNTYNAME" = 'CountyYouWantToShow'
This will only show the polygon for the county you're interested in. Then in Data Frame Properties, Data Frame tab, Clip Options, Clip to Shape, Specify Shape, Outline of Features, pick your county layer in the dropdown.

This will show only features within the county that you specified in the definition query. Save a new MXD for each county.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Data Driven Pages toolbar to automagically generate maps for all counties.